# Como reverter uma pergunta mal avaliada?

Tags: suporte, perguntas-duplicadas, fechamento, reputação

Acredito que minha pergunta é boa, porém foi mal avaliada, só pelo motivo não saberem como responder, além disso, a pessoa que a avaliou concordou  no comentário que ela não é uma duplicata, então não entendo porque foi tratada como uma:

[**O hash do MD5 pode se repetir para senhas diferentes causando colisão**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99194/segundo-especialistas-o-hash-do-md5-pode-se-repetir-para-senhas-diferentes-causa)

Comment: Sua pergunta não está marcada como duplicata, duas pessoas votaram para fechá-la como tal, mas são necessários 5 votos pra pergunta ser fechada de fato, de modo que ela continua aberta. Eu havia votado para fechar como "não clara", mas depois de suas explicações, retirei meu voto. Foi nesse meio tempo que os votos negativos aparecerem, mas como ninguém mais comentou não temos como saber por que ela foi votada dessa forma. Quanto a "reverter", acho difícil, mas se você editar a pergunta para melhorar sua qualidade ela volta ao topo da página principal, mais pessoas poderão vê-la e re-avaliá-la.

Comment: Não me leve a mal, mas o titulo antigo estava meio "nada a ver" com o texto da pergunta, talvez seja por isso que negativaram. Como não sou muito expert no tema em si, não negativei para não ser injusto.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, eu tentei seguir o padrão sugerido por outros usuários que já editaram algumas perguntas minhas removendo o uso da interrogação, para criar uma indexação de título ao assunto.

Comment: A primeira versão da sua pergunta tinha este problema: [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/201), ou seja, ela não era *self-contained*, precisava ir num site externo para ver do que se trata o problema.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Estranho... Na minha cabeça, as perguntas deveriam idealmente ser todas expressas na forma de, bem, uma pergunta... (ex.: "como calcular o módulo em Java?") Mas na prática, muitos escrevem ou no gerúndio ("calculando o módulo em Java") ou em alguma outra forma que não a interrogativa. Com o tempo, passei a ignorar isso (pois parecia uma tarefa de Sísifo tentar consertar). Não vejo mal em escrever de uma ou outra forma, desde que o título não seja completamente irrelevante ou "tautológico" ("dúvida em Java").